# Detect if deleting DataGrid row is valid to delete

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, entity-framework, code-first

I use EF code-first for the datagrid itemsSourse, how can i detect on PreviewKeyUp event if the items the user want to delete is valid to be deleted or not.

For example, if user delete a 'customer', and an 'order' contains customerId it is illegal.
Is there any way to know if the identifier of the item that user want to delete is being used as the foreign key in another table?
Is EF has Any information on it?

Something like that:

```C#
private void DataGridEX_PreviewKeyUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Delete) {
        if (e.OriginalSource is DataGridCell) {
            DataGrid dataGrid = sender;
            if (!IsValidToDelete(dataGrid.SelectedCells)) {
                e.Handled = true;
                MsgBox("Not Valid To Delete !");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're asking if there is any way to find out whether a given value is found in the `CustomerID` column of your `order` table, is that correct? Is your `order` table in your EF model?

Comment: Yes is that correct, and yes `order` is in EF model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like there's a selected row in the `customer` grid, and you're evaluating whether or not to delete that selected `customer`.

And `customer` and `order` are both in your EF model.

So get that `customer`, find his ID, and write a query which checks your `order` table in the EF model for orders with that customer ID. Here's the idea, semantically -- your actual code will look a bit different, no doubt.

```
var selCustomerID = (dataGrid.SelectedRow as customer).customerID;
var customerHasOrder = myEFModel.order.Any(ordr => ordr.customerID == selCustomerID);
```

Think of that `Any` call as being like a loop that'll call the lambda for each row in `myEFModel.order`, and return true the first time the lambda returns true.

```
ordr => ordr.customerID == selCustomerID
```

In reality, of course, since you're doing LINQ to EF, it's generating a SQL query.